# Чтение XML c помощью DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom

Прочитал [статью](https://javaswing.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/java_dom_xml/) и сделал всё по примеру. Все отлично работает. В примере есть теги `class` и `method`. Если, допустим, я добавлю в XML-документ тег `method2`, то как мне вытащить `method` и `method2`?

Вот тут я возвращаю значение атрибута:

```
public String getName() {
    NamedNodeMap attributes = node.getAttributes();
    Node nameAttrib = attributes.getNamedItem("атрибут1");
    return nameAttrib.getNodeValue();
}
```

Если я добавлю новый атрибут в XML-документ, то как мне возвратить несколько?

Весь код идентичен примеру, который можно посмотреть по ссылке вверху.

Исходник XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application>
    <class name = "MainClass">
        <method name = "main"/>
    </class>  
    <class name = "Window">
        <method name = "open"/>
        <method name = "close"/>
        <method name = "show"/>
        <method name = "hide"/>
    </class>      
    <class name = "DataBase">
        <method name = "connect"/>
        <method name = "disconnect"/>
        <method name = "getData"/>
    </class>      
</application>
```

Comment: ссылка не найдена:( Может быть фрагмент кода в вопросе укажете?

Comment: @ArthurEirich гляньте сейчас, все исправил.

Comment: Я в процессе поиска решения)

Comment: @ArthurEirich =) очень признателен.

Comment: @Vladimir991 с чего вы взяли, что между "то" и "как" должна быть запятая в данной ситуации?

Comment: Это правила русского языка. Запятыми выделяются или отделяются обороты, начинающиеся союзом "КАК". В данном случае "как мне вытащить" и "как мне возвратить". Перед союзом "КАК" ставится знак препинания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас добавляется тег *method2* или *method3*, то в общем виде их можно получить используя `node.getChildNodes()` и далее проитерироваться по списку.

В случае добавления атрибутов код у вас уже есть:

`NamedNodeMap attributes = node.getAttributes();`

UPD:

Извиняюсь, писал на коленке.

```
public String getName(Node node) {   // например, тут node - узел Window
    NodeList children = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
        Node methodNode = children.item(0);   // дочерний узел
        NamedNodeMap attributes = methodNode.getAttributes();  // атрибуты дочернего узла
        String name = attributes.getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue(); // значение атрибута
        System.out.println(methodNode + " -> " + name);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: либо я туплю, либо статья неполна, но как мне добыть node?

Comment: Так если допустим у меня несколько Method то в значении node какой из них будет хранится ? Или будет хранить подобно коллекции сразу несколько?

Comment: мне кажется, что нужно просто более точнее изложить ваши затруднения)

Comment: пробую еще раз )
В данном XML файле есть Класс и Метод. У каждого метода есть значение name, которое я вытаскиваю. Допустим в этот же класс, я хочу добавить новый метод с новым значением. Что мне надо изменить в моем коде, что бы извлечь два метода.

Comment: @kxxko

node.getChildNodes() - здесь node это узел, например, с именем Window.
Тогда приведенный метод вернёт список с четырьмя дочерними узлами и, соответственно, в каждом из них будет ровно один атрибут-имя

Comment: А могут быть различные (по имени) узлы и у каждого узла свой атрибут ?

Comment: Конечно могут. Но тогда вам в вашем коде нужно будет это предусмотреть.
Но вообще, при работе с XML также очень полезно использовать XSD (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema)

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25448/discussion-between-kxxko-and-evgeny-lazarev).